# UIView opacity gradient

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uikit, core-graphics

Is it possible to have a UIIView with a textured background image and an opacity gradient?  i.e., the bg image should fade in from left to right against the background container view.

thanks

Comment: just follow the directions in this post and you will figure it out in 30 minutes max:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977947/cagradientlayer-and-scrollviewtexturedbackgroundcolor/4978450#4978450

Answer (score 0):

Save your background image with an alpha channel (i.e. PNG) and do the fade in whatever graphics app you use.

Then, put it as the first child of your UIView as a UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    image1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
    image1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    image2=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"directoryPage.png"]];
    image2.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}

- (void)fade
{   
    image2.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:image2];
    // The upper layer will transition from alpha 1 to 0s
    [self.view addSubview:image1];
    BSheepAppDelegate *appD=(BSheepAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if(appD.flag==0){
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(fadeTimerEvent) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        appD.flag=1;
    }
    else if (appD.flag==1) {
    [self.view addSubview:image2];
    image2.alpha=1;
    }
}

// Rate of transition for alpha values
#define FADE_IN_RATE        1.0/100.0
#define FADE_OUT_RATE   2.0/200.0
- (void)fadeTimerEvent
{
    if (image2.alpha >= 1)
    {
        // At this point, image2 is now visible  
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;   

    }
    else
    { 
      // Fade lower layer in (increase alpha)
        image2.alpha += FADE_IN_RATE;
        // Fade upper layer out (decrease alpha)
        image1.alpha -= FADE_OUT_RATE;
    }
}
```

use this code to set